# Trigger("click") fires only once

Tags: javascript, triggers, click, reportviewer, expand

This is my initial page
[image]

I want to expand all rows and columns programmatically. So, I made a button "TEST"
wich simulate the trigger click for each image (+) using this code

```
$("img").each(function () { 

    $(this).trigger("click");

});
```

And this is the result : only the first column was expanded
[image]

Then I added an alert instruction in my ode like this :

```
$("img").each(function () { 
      alert('HI');
      $(this).trigger("click");

});
```

And it worked. I mean after each time i clicked on the popup to lose it, it expand a row/column. 
I think it needs time between each trigger instruction.
Finally I made a setTimeOut Instruction like that

```
$("img").each(function () { 

            setTimeout(function () {
                $(this).trigger("click");
            }, 2000);

        });
But I got the same problem : only the first column was expanded and that's it.
```

Comment: what happens on click? How is the expand working? I'm trying your example in jsfiddle and is properly working in both cases (despite you forgot a semicolon after the alert).

Comment: Do you want the rows to expand one at a time, but without the alert? Does each row have it's own "a" or are you going for a waterfall effect? It seems like a click event would be triggered anyway when you click the "a" so the code looks a bit redundant...I'd like to help but not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish here. Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: I just edited my question

Comment: I did a quickly sample in [jsfiddle][1] and is working, like @briosheje commented. Can you put your HTML code and JS event click code ? 


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/hrhcnmfe/

Comment: @EduardoE.R. I tried that with simple buttons and it worked perfectly but with <a> or <img> tags that belongs to a ReportViewer control (ASP WEBFORMS) it does not work. I think it's due to the server side handling because while clicking on the (+) to expand, a server side call is raised :\

Comment: If a server side call is raised, then I would personally rather wait until the request has ended before expanding the div.

Comment: @briosheje that's how i made it, i waited that asyhronous task ends from server side

Comment: Wait a second.. Can you please console.log the $(this) which is inside the setTimeout? I have a bad feeling about this, lol.